# Transition probability matrix update

Tags: probability

Let say that there is a field with 3x3 sectors, and a robot walking from one sector to another. We have the robot's movement transition probability matrix $P$ which at initial state has values equals each other, i.e. $$P=  \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
        \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
        \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, lets say the robot's initial position is in  1x2 sector, and it makes movement to 2x2 sector, i.e. transaction matrix $$H = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

What actions do I have to perform in order to update transition probability matrix $P$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the initial distribution on $S = \{1,2,3\}^2$, which is uniform and should be represented as the row vector
$$
  \left( \frac{1}{9}, \ldots, \frac{1}{9} \right),
$$
with a matrix.
The transition matrix specifies the probability of moving from a point $i \in S$ to a point $j \in S$; since there are $9^2=81$ such pairs, you need a $9\times 9 $ matrix, not a $3 \times 3$. Additionally, it is most likely the case that you are dealing with a fixed transition kernel governing the movement from one state to the next at a given point in time, i.e. a Markov chain.

Are you sure you didn't mean something else? Perhaps you wanted your state space to just be $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right that transaction matrix should be 9x9, I was confused. And then at initial values should be distributed uniformly. But question is , how to update this matrix if I know what movement performed? May be you can define movement matrix as well?

Comment: The "movement" matrix is just the kernel of a Markov chain. The thing you want to update isn't that, but rather the distribution at time $n$. Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_matrix